# In R, how do I selectively 'copy and paste' a cell into another cell based on specific row/column criteria?

Tags: r, copy-paste, transformation, data-wrangling

I have some data (see below) whereby I have participants (`ID` column) who have a score on three variables (`Name_A`, `Name_B`, and `Name_C`). These scores are currently recorded against the associated variable horizontally in the `X1Score`, `X2Score`, and `X3Score` columns. I would like these scores 'copied and pasted' (for lack of a better phrase) to the associated columns – being `Name_A`, `Name_B`, and `Name_C` (currently filled with `NA`) – so that I have the data in long format. How do I do this?

```
ID  X1      X1Score X2      X2Score X3      X3Score Name_A    Name_B  Name_C
1   Name_A  4.58    Name_C  4.79    Name_B  5.22    NA        NA      NA
2   Name_C  5.35    Name_B  5.33    Name_A  5.61    NA        NA      NA
3   Name_B  5.59    Name_C  5.48    Name_A  4.89    NA        NA      NA
4   Name_C  5.36    Name_B  5.04    Name_A  4.93    NA        NA      NA
5   Name_A  5.39    Name_B  5.27    Name_C  5.11    NA        NA      NA
6   Name_C  4.91    Name_A  4.99    Name_B  5.01    NA        NA      NA



df <- structure(list(ID = 1:6,
                         X1 = c("Name_A", "Name_C", "Name_B", "Name_C", "Name_A", "Name_C"),
                         X1Score = c(4.58, 5.35, 5.59, 5.36, 5.39, 4.91),
                         X2 = c("Name_C", "Name_B", "Name_C", "Name_B", "Name_B", "Name_A"),
                         X2Score = c(4.79, 5.33, 5.48, 5.04, 5.27, 4.99),
                         X3 = c("Name_B", "Name_A", "Name_A", "Name_A", "Name_C", "Name_B"),
                         X3Score = c(5.22, 5.61, 4.89, 4.93, 5.11, 5.01),
                         Name_A = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                         Name_B = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                         Name_C = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),
                    row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

#Edit: My original request above is too simplistic and, although the answer technically addressed the question, I failed to understand how to generalise it. So, here is a revised example (where the only major difference is the naming convention of the columns) - this example produces an error, despite the same code working on the above example. My hope is that with another example of my problem, I will be able to make sense of the `'X\\d+(.*)'` line as it looks like this is the key to making it work. Here is the updated example:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:6,
                     X1_Name = c("Name_A", "Name_C", "Name_B", "Name_C", "Name_A", "Name_C"),
                     X1_Score = c(4.58, 5.35, 5.59, 5.36, 5.39, 4.91),
                     X5_Name = c("Name_C", "Name_B", "Name_C", "Name_B", "Name_B", "Name_A"),
                     X5_Score = c(4.79, 5.33, 5.48, 5.04, 5.27, 4.99),
                     X19_Name = c("Name_B", "Name_A", "Name_A", "Name_A", "Name_C", "Name_B"),
                     X19_Score = c(5.22, 5.61, 4.89, 4.93, 5.11, 5.01)),
                row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

df %>%
  #get the data in long format creating two columns Name and Score
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, 
               names_to = '.value',
               names_pattern = 'X\\d+(.*)') %>%
  #Get data in wide format. 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Name, values_from = Score)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may perform reshaping with `pivot_longer`/`pivot_wider` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  #To drop empty NA columns
  select(-starts_with('Name')) %>%
  #Rename X1 to X1Name, X2 to X2Name and so on
  rename_with(~paste0(., 'Name'), matches('^X\\d+$')) %>%
  #get the data in long format creating two columns Name and Score
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, 
               names_to = '.value',
               names_pattern = 'X\\d+(.*)') %>%
  #Get data in wide format. 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Name, values_from = Score)

#     ID Name_A Name_C Name_B
#  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1   4.58   4.79   5.22
#2     2   5.61   5.35   5.33
#3     3   4.89   5.48   5.59
#4     4   4.93   5.36   5.04
#5     5   5.39   5.11   5.27
#6     6   4.99   4.91   5.01
```

If you want to keep all other columns in the data as it is and add these 3 columns separately you may join the dataset with the original one.

```
...Code from above %>%
   left_join(df %>% select(-starts_with('Name')), by = 'ID')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Strictly speaking, you have answered my question and your code clearly works. The problem is I can't use it because I can't figure out how generalise it to other very similar situations (the example I gave is purely for the purpose of Stack overflow - my actual data is commercially sensitive so I can't share it). What I really need is a way to generalise the solution to other situations where, for example, "Name" is not used. Your code seems to have a step where all of the X1, X1Score, X2, X2Score columns get collapsed into two columns. I think this is key somehow.

Comment: I think the thing that is stopping me from generalising the code is the matches command with all of those strange symbols ((matches('^X\\d+$')). What do they mean?

Comment: Yup, the key is to create 2 unique groups of columns which can be easily distinguished by their name.  In your example, the two groups of columns that you had were Group 1 - `X1`, `X2`, `X3` and Group 2 - `X1Score`, `X2Score`, `X3Score`. I change the names of Group 1 to `X1Name`, `X2Name` and `X3Name`, `matches('^X\\d+$')` matches the names of `X1`, `X2` and `X3`. So the two groups are now `Name` and `Score` in `pivot_longer`. I think it will be easier to understand if you run the code one step at a time and see it's output

Comment: I can see what each step does, but I still don't understand how it does it. What does the (matches('^X\\d+$') and names_pattern = 'X\\d+(.*)' mean?

Comment: I have added another example to the question in the hopes that my problem is a little clearer.